# Get a specific data from database and print it

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get a specific value from Firebase Database with child name "totalExercise" and print it using swift. Here is the current content of firebase database.

[image]

And here is my code in swift trying to get and print the totalExercise value

[image]

Comment: I think it is because your node title is, effectively, optional. Which, in itself isn’t a problem, but you are unwrapping it when you are querying Firebase by using (user?.uid)!

Comment: In the future, please use text versions of your firebase structure and code instead of screen shots so we can use that in our answer without having to retype it. You can get Firebase as text using the Firebase Console->Export JSON and then you can copy/paste your structure and code in your question.

Comment: @Paulo yes you are right.Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jay Yes I will post as a text next time. It was my first time posting a question here so I was not familiar to the custom here but yeah thanks for the feedback. I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a literal answer to your question but please read on

```
let loginRef = self.ref.child("fblogintest-35707").child("Optional(\"gl8...\")")

loginRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let val = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
    let te = val["totalExercise"]
    print(te)
})
```

the gl8 is a long string which I didnt feel like retyping so just insert that from your question. This code will print '10'

That being said, there are a number of issues with  the Firebase structure and the code in the question.

As you can see, whatever the code is that's creating the keys in your question is creating them as Optionals and that should not be done as the actual string of "Optional("gl8..") is being written to Firebase.. That's why you see the word Optional in your structure.

You should probably do some unwrapping/error checking on ref? and user? as well so if they are nil (they are optionals) the code doesn't crash.

If you haven't done so, read up on [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) as they are super powerful but you got to wrap your brain around how to implement them effectively to protect your code.

Comment: thank you very much.your code answer was very helpful and it works!